# bash alias with args works in one environment, not in another

Tags: linux, bash, shell, alias

I've seen many posts indicating that shell aliases don't support args. In one environment, CentOS 6.10, Bash 4.1.2, I have this:

```
alias hist='source ~/scripts/hist "@$"'
```

(~/scripts/hist is a shell script)
This works. The script accurately receives the passed args from the alias. In another environment - RHEL Server 7.5, Bash 4.2.46 with a similar alias - the only difference being an explicit path in the alias:

```
alias hist='source /full/path/to/hist "@$"'
```

Does not work. When the script runs, it believes it has received args like: "uid=nnnn(username) gid=nnnn(grpname) groups=nnnn(grp)"

The script is exactly identical in both places. I'm just wondering what the explanation could be.

Comment: maybe it was "$@", but may not do expected, in the better case (current shell parameters are not set) is useless because expanded to nothing, worst case current shell parameters are set see `echo "$@"`

Comment: Sorry for the typo folks - "$@" above, not "@$"...

Comment: could you do `echo "$@"` in the command line of shell where it doesn't work and compare with the shell where it works

Answer (score 2):

it doesn't work as expected, here a minimal example

```
alias print_args='printf "<%s>\n" "$@"'

print_args "hello" "world"
```

may print

```
<hello>
<world>
```

but only if current shell parameters are not set (which is sometimes be true in interactive shell but not always)

however after `set 1 2 3`  for example

```
set -- 1 2 3
print_args "hello" "world"
```

prints

```
<1>
<2>
<3>
<hello>
<world>
```

command line positionnal parameters are next to current positionnal parameters.

Whereas following (without `"$@"`) passed correctly command line parameters

```
alias print_args='printf "<%s>\n"'
print_args "hello" "world"
```